# How to search in database using select query using data from excel file?

Tags: mysql, excel, toad

I am have data in a excel file shown below with thousands of records.

[image]

There are only 3 columns with thousands of record.

I have to search a particular property from database for all values in column 3 only.

Is it possible that I can create a query like **"select * from table_name where property in ('68487938' , '47716670' ....for all column 3 values);"**

OR

Is there any other way?
I am using MySQL and Toad.

Comment: Hi @basha04, Could you please write the steps how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

@Mayank Kumar Thakur as you asked in the comments and  hope I did understand well what you are asking , you can follow below steps.

Let say you have the table:

```
create table `table01` (
id int(9) not null auto_increment,
nr_1 int(9) default null ,
nr_2 int(9) default null ,
property int(9) default null ,
Primary key id(`id`) );

insert into  table01 values (1,49,151,684598), (2,49,151,6845498),(3,49,151,45684598),(4,49,151,23684598),(5,49,151,14684598),(6,49,151,68459801),(7,49,151,68459802),(8,49,151,68459803),(9,49,151,68459804),(10,49,151,68459805),(11,49,151,68459806),(12,49,151,68459807);
```

And you want all the data only for the property 68459804','68459805','68459806','68459807, you can do the following query, it's the same in your question.

```
select * from table01 where property in ('68459804','68459805','68459806','68459807');
```

If `property` column is not indexed you can do it :

```
alter table table01 add key property(`property`);
```

If you want all the values on property column you can write

```
select * from table01 where property in (select distinct property from table01) ;
```

Comment: Hi @basha04, I have thousands of records in excel file. How can I write "select * from table01 where property in ('68459804','68459805','68459806','68459807', ...., );" query including all the values of column 3 from my table?